# Code not working, Sorting MySQL results into pages

Tags: php, mysql, paging

Ok so iv got this code which is suppose to bring back all my results from my database and display 5 results per page.  At the moment I have 12 results in my database and it is only showing 10, it wont show the 3rd page as there isnt 5 results to display.  Here is my code

```
//$_GET['page'] is to get the current page opened
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };
$results_per_page = "5"; //number of results I want displayed per page
$start_from = ($page-1) * $results_per_page; 
$query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE subcat = '$conditions' LIMIT $start_from, $results_per_page";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to verify user because : " . mysql_error());
while ($row_condition=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   //Display the results here
}

//Count number of results from database and work out how
//many pages I need to display all the results.    
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE subcat = '$conditions'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result1);
$num_pages = $num_rows / $results_per_page;

if ($num_rows > $results_per_page){
?>
<div id="pagenum">
<?php
//This creates and displays the page numbers for the user to select
foreach( range( 1, $num_pages) as $i) {
     if ($thepage == $i){
           echo '<b><a href="browse.php?condition=' . $condition . '&page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a></b>';
     }else{
           echo '<a href="browse.php?condition=' . $condition . '&page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a>';
     }

     //This places a line between each number of pages
     if ($i == $num_pages){
     }else{
         echo " | ";
     }
     }
?>
</div>
<?php
     }else{ echo "Test";}
?>
```

So can anyone see a problem with this?, so I have 12 entries in my database.  However im only getting 2 pages, 5 on each page and im not getting the 3rd page as there are only 2 results left and it seems to want 5 to finish it.
Thanks

Comment: Side note: to get number of records, it's enough to call `SELECT COUNT(*) ....`, absolutely no need to read all records.

Comment: I did origionally have this, I cant remember why I changed it now, but I remember something didnt work properly so I changed it to this which worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [ceil](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) function:

```
$num_pages = ceil($num_rows / $results_per_page);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your biggest problem is that PHP will make give you a float when you divide two numbers that don't result in a whole one.

```
$one = 12;
$two = 5;
$result = $one / $two; // That will result in 2.4
```

Now, the issue is you, technically, have three pages, but PHP will NOT treat the .4 pages as a page, so when you loop through it will technically only do it twice. Since your using range and it's 2.4, it seems like PHP is rounding down. I would suggest something like this:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE subcat = '$conditions'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result1);
$num_pages = ceil($num_rows / $results_per_page);

if ($num_rows > $results_per_page){
    for($i = 0; $i < $num_pages; $i++) {
```

[ceil()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) will force that division to round up every time, which will always give you that extra page.

Give it a shot! Let me know if it fixes your issue!

Comment: Yes this did work, the guy before you posted the ceil() thing as well.  So thanks :)